# JavaScript img.style.top and img.style.left not working

Tags: javascript, image, display, appendchild, createelement

I can't get an image positioned properly from JavaScript using **img.style.top** and **img.style.left**, it's always showing on top left, unless I use the CSS.  Please help this newbie.

```
<---css file--->
.imgTable {
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
}
.imgDeal {
    position: absolute;
    transform: scale(.5);
    //top: 60px;                     // --- this works ---
    //left: 470px;                   // --- this works ---
    z-index: 1
}

<--- html file --->
div class="table-body">
    <div class=imgTable>
        <img src="images/table.png">
        <div id="imgDeal" class="imgDeal"> </div>
    </div>
</div>

<--- JS file --->
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = "images/deal.png";
img.style.top = "60px";              // --- this does not work ---
img.style.left = "470px";            // --- this does not work ---
document.getElementById('imgDeal').appendChild(img);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JavaScript code adds the inline style to your newly created img element but not to your .imgDeal div element. Your newly created img element is not positioned absolutely or fixed, so the `top` and `left` css rules have no effect.

One possible solution can be changing your CSS code from

```
.imgDeal {
    position: absolute;
    transform: scale(.5);
    z-index: 1
}
```

to

```
.imgDeal img {
    position: absolute;
    transform: scale(.5);
    z-index: 1
}
```

and optionally giving your .imgDeal div element a fix width and height.

Comment: I've changed to ".imgDeal img", and added fixed width and height to ".imgTable" tag, and it worked!!!  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

`left` and `top` do nothing if an element is `position: static` (which is the default) which you are overriding with plain CSS but not with JS.